# Configuration Version is missing Terraform Cloud

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I set up a workspace and I am following the [Enforce Policy with Sentinel](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/policy) hands on guide.

I see the following message in the run tab:

[image]
As soon as I try to press the queue plan button I receive this error:

[image]

My configured variables are:

[image]
Is there something else I need to configure to be able to queue a plan?

Executing from the cli I was able to trigger a run (in TF Cloud) that only included the plan step. The run execution can be viewed if I access the specific run url directly.

Any help, suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915515/configuration-version-is-missing-terraform-cloud ?

Comment: This is my question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've already resolved this issue, but I post my resolution anyway.

When this issue occurred, I had wrong workspace's name settings.

There were two workspaces with similar names, and I don't know why this happened. Then I deleted one of them.

On the other one occurred this issue.

In the end, when I deleted the workspace and recreated it, I didn't have the issue occurring anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't have duplicate / similar names workspaces (only one workspace). I found that after running `terraform apply` locally once first, the UI controls started to work as expected.